# How fast is your GREP in Cygwin?

Tags: linux, performance, cygwin, grep

I'm using Cygwin in a very fast PC but I find it is ridiculously slow when I want to use grep. It also slow when I want to process a large file (say 25Mb). Here I'm using an example to prove my case.

```
> time for i in $(seq 1000); do grep "$i" .; done

real 75.865     user 5.442      sys 14.542      pcpu 26.34
```

I want to know

1. **Show me your score. Have you had similar problem with slowness of cygwin or GNU grep**
2. **How can you improve the performance**
3. **What your tips of using Cygwin**

> uname -rvs
>   CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 1.7.9(0.237/5/3) 2011-03-29 10:10

```
which grep
grep is /usr/bin/grep
grep is /bin/grep
grep is /usr/bin/grep`
```

Comment: `grep foo .` shouldn't do _anything_ -- `.` refers to a directory, which cannot be read.

Comment: Doesn't grepping over the same 25 MiB file 1000 times mean that you're effectively processing 25,000 MiB (25 GiB) of data? How quickly were you expecting this to finish? (provided your command is correct)

Comment: Also, you are grepping for very short strings ("1" .. "1000"). GNU grep may decide to use Boyer-Moore on longer strings. _Morale:_ benchmark using realistic scenarios.

Comment: You're largely testing `fork()` performance there by asking for 1000 grep processes. Cygwin's `fork()` is slow because implementing it on Windows requires an almighty hack.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ time for i in $(seq 1000); do grep "$i" .; done

real    0m13.741s
user    0m3.520s
sys     0m8.577s

$ uname -rvs
CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 1.7.15(0.260/5/3) 2012-05-09 10:25

$ which grep
/usr/bin/grep
```